# Unique topology mapping scenario for web application

Tags: cme, web8.5, broker, topology-manager, dxa-1.7

I am moving from 2013 with DXA 1.2 to 8.5 with DXA 1.7 with Topology Manager based publishing.

In my old application, following used to be my Url for LIVE and STAGING.

https://mydomain:8080/LIVE/channel/sg/pagename.htm
https://mydomain:8082/STAGING/channel/sg/pagename.htm

We use the same domain for LIVE and STAGING and are only differentiated by the context (LIVE vs. STAGING). Within SDL Tridion content manager, we use /channel/ as the publication path and URL.

To keep the URLs consistent, we implemented the UrlRewrite.Net module and use the delete-element [per the link](https://github.com/Bikeman868/UrlRewrite.Net#delete-element) to remove the first path element (LIVE OR STAGING).

So the urlPath passed to DXA 1.2 /channel/sg/pagename.htm irrespective of LIVE or STAGING configuration. I have about 200,000 items being published with the above configuration. Given the volume of items, I intend to use [Convert-TcmPublishStates](https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/tridion-developer/b/weblog/posts/sdl-web-8-migrating-from-old-to-new-style-publishing-part-1-of-3-the-cmdlet) script to map the old publication target to the newly created one to avoid republishing of content.

In the TPM way of resolution, we are seeing a couple of TPM options available to us.  We have made the publication URL blank in the CME. Dumb from Get-TtmMapping is below.

**Option 1**

```
EnvironmentPurpose  : LIVE
WebApplicationId    : myChannelApp
RelativeUrl         : /
PrimaryMappedUrl    : https://mydomain:8080/LIVE/channel
```

The problem is that /LIVE/channel is being added BPT mapped to the publication. Since I intend NOT to republish the items, any old items published to the broker are NOT coming up fine. In the CM side, I noticed that URL is a read-only attribute. Is it advisable to change the URL in Tridion CM side to match my broker settings? Any recommendations?

**Option 2**

```
EnvironmentPurpose  : LIVE
WebApplicationId    : myChannelApp
RelativeUrl         : /
PrimaryMappedUrl    : https://mydomain:8080/channel
```

The web application is working perfectly once the settings are re-published. The only problem is that the "View on Site" within the CME is broken. The URL from the CME would be https://mydomain/channel instead of https://mydomain/LIVE/channel. I would have to use the above delete-element rule with this configuration.

See below a sample dump from our broker database.

[image]

Feedback is appreciated!

**Update:**
Since we use different ports for LIVE and STAGING, we will setup 2 discovery services with our capabilities. We tested XPM and it is working as expected!

Comment: How is your current web app setup is it both Staging and Live pointing to same broker DB for components links and DCPs?, Is there any reason not to create 2 specific DNS URL for staging and live?

Comment: It seems to me definitely you are not doing the right way, how your XPM setup will work for this?

Comment: The primary "mydomain" in the above part is being used by our internal authentication and hence drives both the URL. We internally resolve /LIVE/ and /STAGING/ with different ports and hence the authorities will vary. Since we have a port in the BaseURL, we will have 2 discovery services with our capabilities pointing to different database. I have updated the question with the port as part of the URL as well.

Comment: Indeed!, It clear to me, you have unique URL for both staging and live, then based on your question you have own answer already, what is your question?

Comment: It will not since the "View on Site" functionality will not be working. If I go with Option 1, I will have to republish the items (to include the context) or remove the /LIVE/ or /STAGING/ in the BPT.Path.

Comment: yes. If you ask me I would recommend creating the nice DNS URL independently for staging and live, eg. https://staging.mydomain/ and https://live.mydomain/ - don't include LIVE or STAGING in the path, with or without port as per your firewall IT decision. it will work View on Site feature and no need to republish your pages.

Comment: I agree with you on having 2 separate domains in the long-run but was wondering if I could somehow manipulate the Path that is being sent to the broker when using Topology Manager. I will keep digging. If we can, I would want to resolve the issue the I am facing in code. Let's see!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86735/discussion-between-velmurugan-and-shiva).